# Is it possible to create new instance of primitive of user defined POJO

Tags: java, reflection

i have class `TestClass` is it possible to create new instance for this during runtime ?
like the way we create `TestClass someObj = new TestClass(); also TestClass[] someObj = new TestClass();` same thing for java primitive types also.

Is it possible through reflection if so kindly support the answer with example.

EDIT:

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class SampleNoArg {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Rectangle r = (Rectangle) createObject("java.awt.Rectangle");
      System.out.println(r.toString());
   }

   static Object createObject(String className) {
      Object object = null;
      try {
          Class classDefinition = Class.forName(className);
          object = classDefinition.newInstance();
      } catch (InstantiationException e) {
          System.out.println(e);
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
          System.out.println(e);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
          System.out.println(e);
      }
      return object;
   }
}
```

same like the above but i want to create some times array of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use [Class#newInstance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) for instantiating an array:

> InstantiationException - if this Class represents an abstract class, an interface, **an array class**, a primitive type, or void; or if the class has no nullary constructor; or if the instantiation fails for some other reason.

Here is a possible workaround:

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T[] newArray(Class<T> clazz, int n) {
    return (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, n);
}
```